# merging 3 sorted arrays

Tags: java, algorithm, mergesort

```
public class array12 {
    static void merge_sort(int A[], int start, int end) {
        if (end - start > 1) {
            int middle1 = (2 * start + end + 1) / 3 - 1;
            int middle2 = 2 * middle1 - start + 1;

            merge_sort(A, start, middle1); 

            merge_sort(A, middle1 + 1, middle2);

            merge_sort(A, middle2 + 1, end);

            merge(A, start, middle1, middle2, end);
        }
    }

    static void merge(int[] x, int start, int middle1, int middle2, int end) {
        int n1 = middle1 - start + 1;

        int n2 = middle2 - middle1;

        int n3 = end - middle2;

        int left[] = new int[n1];  // defining and initialising three arrays .

        int mid[] = new int[n2];

        int right[] = new int[n3];

        for (int i = 0; i < left.length; i++) {
            left[i] = x[i + start];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < mid.length; i++) {
            mid[i] = x[i + middle1 + 1];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < right.length; i++) {
            right[i] = x[i + middle2 + 1];
        }

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        int c = start;


        // finding minimum element from the three arrays .

            while (i < n1 && j < n2 && k < n3) {
            if (left[i] <= mid[j] && left[i] <= right[k]) {
                x[c] = left[i];
                i++;
                c++;
            } else if (mid[j] <= left[i] && mid[j] <= right[k]) {
                x[c] = mid[j];
                j++;
                c++;
            } else {
                x[c] = right[k];
                k++;
                c++;
            }
        }

        // now only two arrays are left to be compared

        while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
            if (left[i] <= mid[j]) {
                x[c] = left[i];
                i++;
                c++;
            } else {
                x[c] = mid[j];
                j++;
                c++;
            }
        }

        while (j < n2 && k < n3) {
            if (mid[j] <= right[k]) {
                x[c] = mid[j];
                j++;
                c++;
            } else {
                x[c] = right[k];
                k++;
                c++;
            }
        }

        while (i < n1 && k < n3) {
            if (left[i] <= right[k]) {
                x[c] = left[i];
                i++;
                c++;
            } else {
                x[c] = right[k];
                k++;
                c++;
            }
        }

        // now only single array is left out of left[] , mid[] and right[].
        while (i < n1) {
            x[c] = left[i];
            i++;
            c++;
        }

        while (j < n2) {
            x[c] = mid[j];
            j++;
            c++;
        }

        while (k < n3) {
            x[c] = right[k];
            k++;
            c++;
        }

        System.out.println("");

        // printing array elements after every merge operation .

        for (int e = 0; e < x.length; e++) {
            System.out.print(x[e] + "  ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] x = new int[9];

        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i] = x.length - i;
        }
        System.out.println("initial array is : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(x[i] + "  ");
        }

        System.out.println("");
        merge_sort(x, 0, x.length - 1);

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(" sorted array is : ");

        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(x[i] + "  ");
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to merge 3 sorted arrays . I have been able to develop code for array size equal to power of 3 . I am unable to implement it with some other array size . I have tried to change values of middle1 and middle2 but am experiencing serious trouble . Setting their values is the main concern . Merging step is quite simple and is not causing problems .
What changes are required in my code so that it may work for any array size ? Can it be implemented using this approach ? I dont want size of any of the three arrays , left[] , mid[] and right[] to be zero at any time .
Please help .

Comment: what is the merge condition ?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: I mean, how do you wanted to merge, as your code is so lengthy, need an hour to understand your code.

Comment: You should print the values of `start`, `end`, `middle1`, and `middle2`. Make sure they look sensible.

Comment: You can make arrays out of some Collections.  Using an ArrayList or something is an intermediate might help you with all this nasty index math. But, yeah. I don't think you have communicated the actual requirements.

Comment: I am just trying to divide the main array into 3 parts at every step . I dont want size of any array ( left[] , mid[] or right[] ) to be 0 . I am experiencing problem when size of array is not power of 3 ; for example if I have array of size 4 initially or at any step then I want first array to be size 2 , second of 1 and third of also 1 .

Comment: @jdv main concern for me is setting the values of middle1 and middle2 . Merging the three arrays is not really a big concern .

Comment: @shikhar clarifications to the question should be in the body of the question, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar answer to [YCF_L's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48409186/7294647), but simplified (still uses Java 8):

```
public static int[] sortMultipleArrays(int[]... arrays) {
    return Arrays.stream(arrays)
                 .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
                 .sorted()
                 .toArray();
}
```

Output:

> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 17, 20, 21, 24]

Comment: The point of the code in the question is to implement a merge sort. Replacing the merge part of the logic with a built-in sort is definitely not the right answer. If you're going to use the built-in sort, you'd replace the entire merge sort logic, not just the merge part of it, and you'd do it by replacing the original `merge_sort(x, 0, x.length - 1)` call with [`Arrays.sort(x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-), not by using streams.

Answer (score -1):

I don't follow your merge code. It seems overly complicated.

Here is a method for merging an unlimited number of sorted arrays, each a varying size.

```
private static int[] mergeSortedArrays(int[]... arrays) {
    int totalLen = 0;
    for (int[] arr : arrays)
        totalLen += arr.length;
    int[] idx = new int[arrays.length];
    int[] merged = new int[totalLen];
    for (int i = 0; i < totalLen; i++) {
        int min = 0, minJ = -1;
        for (int j = 0; j < arrays.length; j++)
            if (idx[j] < arrays[j].length)
                if (minJ == -1 || min > arrays[j][idx[j]]) {
                    min = arrays[j][idx[j]];
                    minJ = j;
                }
        merged[i] = min;
        idx[minJ]++;
    }
    return merged;
}
```

*Test*

```
int[] a = { 3, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21 };
int[] b = { 2, 10, 20 };
int[] c = { 1, 7, 12, 24 };
int[] d = { 6 };
int[] merged = mergeSortedArrays(a, b, c, d);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(merged));
```

*Output*

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 17, 20, 21, 24]
```

Comment: Shouldn't your min  = INT.MAX instead of 0, because otherwise how will the check min > arrays[j][idx[j]] go through ? just curious

Comment: @zenwraight The `minJ == -1` means that initial value of `min` doesn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

If using class "Integer" instead of primitive int is not a problem you can use this, basically first do the merge and after sort them: you can do the call Arrays.sort even in the same method and call it mergeAndSort, if you want...

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static Integer[] merge(Integer[]... arrays) {

        int count = 0;
        for (Integer[] array : arrays) {
            count += array.length;
        }

        Integer[] mergedArray = (Integer[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(arrays[0][0].getClass(), count);
        int start = 0;
        for (Integer[] array : arrays) {
            System.arraycopy(array, 0, mergedArray, start, array.length);
            start += array.length;
        }
        return mergedArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] array1 = {3, 5, 6, 7, 78, 100};
        Integer[] array2 = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
        Integer[] array3 = {2, 6, 7};
        Integer[] merged1 = merge(array1, array2);
        Arrays.sort(merged1);
        Integer[] merged2 = merge(array1, array2, array3);
        Arrays.sort(merged2);
        printArray(merged1);
        printArray(merged2);

    }

    public static void printArray(Integer[] x) {
        System.out.println("--ToString--");
        for (Integer var : x) {
            System.out.println(var);
        }
        System.out.println("----");

    }
}
```